# NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE only with NETBIOS

Tags: samba, samba4

I Have Two computer with hostnames *Computer-A* and *Computer-B*. *Computer-B* **can** access *Computer-A* with both IP and NetBios but *Computer-A* **can't** access *Computer-B* with NetBios so

```
smbclient -U username //Computer-A/homes              <----executed on Computer-B
smbclient -U username //<Computer-B IP Address>/homes <----executed on Computer-A
```

works but

```
smbclient -U username //Computer-B/homes              <----executed on Computer-A
```

return `NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE`

### Info

- both computer running Arch linux, have SMBD, NMBD, WindBindd running.
- Computer A have Samba 4.5.9, Computer B have Samba 4.7.5
- both computer have exactly the same smb.conf, nsswitch.conf which can be accessed [smb.conf](https://paste.gnome.org/ptfkywpso) [nsswitch.conf](https://paste.gnome.org/pzklhkjg2)
- both computer have same username configured through smbpasswd and ...
- running `nbtscan -v 192.168.88.0/24` on Computer-A give [this output](https://paste.gnome.org/pehlo6kol) so netbios of Computer-B can be seen from Computer-A but still smbclient return `NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE`.
- Computer A have fixed IP-address but Computer B use DHCP so have dynamic IP-address

there is no error in systemctl status/Samba log. why this weird problem happening? I tried all possible test but with no luck.

Comment: Try `nmblookup Computer-B` and `nmblookup -A Computer-B-IP` and see if  you get any errors

Comment: @HeshamAhmed Thanks for your comment, running `nmblookup Computer-B` return `192.168.88.88 Computer-B<00>` and no error when using IP. This is very strange to me that the nbtscan and nmblookup can see the netbios but samba can't. I run smbclient again right after successful nmblookup but result is the same. Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE